# Conections between Parseval's Identities

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces, fourier-series

I know how to prove that if $f,g \in \mathcal{S}$ (Schwartz space - or even ${L}^2$), then $$f*g \in \mathcal{S}$$ and $$\|f\|_2^2=\|\widehat{f}\|_2^2.$$ Here,  $$\|f\|_2=\sqrt{<f,f>}= \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x)|^2 dx\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
and the identity is called Parseval's identity.

And I know that if  $$S[f]= \frac{a_0}{2}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n f_n(x)+b_ng_n(x)),$$ is the Fourier serie of $f$, in which $f_n(x)=\cos\frac{n \pi x}{L}$ and $g_n(x)=\sin\frac{n \pi x}{L}$, we have
$$\frac{1}{2}a_0^2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n^2 + b_n^2)= \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^L |f(x)|^2 dx$$
that is called Parseval's identity too.

I would like to know what is the connection between these two Parseval identities.

It is obvious that the norm of the Fourier Transform ends up having a connection with the coefficients of the Fourier series of $f$. Would it be just that?

Thaks a lot!

Cleto

Comment: They both say that the Fourier transform (in the general sense) is an isometry.

Comment: Thanks @QiaochuYuan ! In the first case I understand the isometry in $\mathcal{S}$, but in the second, I still can't stablish a conexion.